# How to test axios api using jest and react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

this is my apis.js where my axios logic is written

```
import axios from 'axios'

function logSuccess(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req, res)

  next(res)
}

function logError(req, res, e, next) {
  console.log(req, res, e)

  next(e)
}

function getResource(url, onComplete) {
  let _onSuccess = (res) => logSuccess(url, res, onComplete)
  let _onError = (res, e) => logError(url, res, e, onComplete)
  let _onException = (e) => logError(url, null, e, onComplete)

  axios
    .get(url)

    .then((res) => {
      res ? _onSuccess(res) : _onError(res)
    }, _onException)

    .catch(_onException)
}

function postResource(url, data, cancelTokenSource, onComplete) {
  let _onSuccess = (res) => logSuccess(url, res, onComplete)
  let _onError = (res, e) => logError(url, res, e, onComplete)
  let _onException = (e) => logError(url, null, e, onComplete)

  axios
    .post(url, data, { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token })

    .then((res) => {
      res ? _onSuccess(res) : _onError(res)
    }, _onException)

    .catch(_onException)
}

const apis = {
  getResource,
  postResource,
}

export default apis
```

this is my other file where i have called axios functions:

```
    import apis from '../../commonUtils/apis/apis'

export default class LookingGlassAPIs {
  constructor(params) {
    let { apiRoot } = params

    this.routers = {}
    this.commandRequests = {}

    this.routers.getAll = (...rest) =>
      apis.getResource(apiRoot + 'routers', ...rest)
    this.commandRequests.post = (...rest) =>
      apis.postResource(apiRoot + 'commandRequests', ...rest)
  }
}
 const apiRoot = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
```

i am new to react i donot know to write test case for axios without hitting api.can any one please help me.url is defined in another file but for reference i have decalred here only . should i use   axios.get.mockResolvedValue(data)???Is it right way??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must mock axios and look if axios methods are called with the right parameters for example.

apis.spec.js

```js
import apis from './apis';

jest.mock('axios'); // This overwrites axios methods with jest Mock
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Test Apis', () => {
    describe('getResource', () => {
        describe('with success', () => {
            const url = 'http://test-url.com';
            const onComplete = jest.fn();
            const data = {};

            beforeEach(() => {
                axios.get.mockResolvedValue(data);
            });

            it('should call axios get with given url', () => {
                getResource(url, onComplete);
                expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith(url);
            });

            it('should call onComplete callback with response', async () => { // do not forget 'async'
                await getResource(url, onComplete); // notice the 'await' because onComplete callback is called in '.then'
                expect(onComplete).toBeCalledWith(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You could do the same with the error response and POST method. You could also test your `LookingGlassAPIs` by mocking your `apis.js` methods, or again by mocking `axios`, it depends of your "unit" definition inside your project.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the functions you want to test don't return anything, you could test if they throw or no.

You would need to spy your axios methods, mocking a return value (in this case a Promise), something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
    
beforeAll(() => {
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('whatever-get'));
  axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('whatever-post'));
});
    
afterAll(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
    
test('get does not throw', () => {
  expect(getResource()).not.toThrow();
});
    
test('post does not throw', () => {
  expect(postResource()).not.toThrow();
});
```

Comment: did you mean to call expect(apis.getResource()).not.toThrow();???? And how check what is result of get ???

Comment: If you are exporting both functions like `{getResource, postResource}` yes. The thing is that you are not saving the fetch results anywhere..

Comment: did this expect(apis.getResource('http://127.0.0.1:8080/routers')).not.toThrow()  and got error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined ?? any help??

Comment: thanks for updated answer. but still i got the same error.